# How to root blackview a20

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a [blackview A20](http://www.blackview.hk/blackview-274/) which is a [low spec](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/0c8849ab) phone running [android oreo go](https://www.android.com/versions/oreo-8-0/go-edition/).

I would like to use this phone for experimentation with android development and learning about android on a cheap device without risk of breaking my main phone. To do this I would like it rooted and as a bonus with a custom recovery so I can test custom ROMs.

### State of device:

- Unlocked bootloader
- Unchanged ROM
- Unchanged Recovery
- OEM unlocking enabled
- USB debugging enabled

### What I have tried:

- **Flashing recovery images with fastboot**

  Using `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` with some TWRP and CWM recovery images all yield:

  ```
  target reported max download size of 134217728 bytes
  sending 'recovery' (4690 KB)...
  OKAY [  0.169s]
  writing 'recovery'...
  OKAY [  0.276s]
  finished. total time: 0.448s
  ```

  or similar. Then I restart phone and select boot into recovery mode. The phone hangs for a small while before restarting and booting into the normal OS. On restart into recovery the unchanged recovery is there still.
- **Various 'one-tap' methods**

  All of which were unsuccessful. If needed I can give details.
- **Installing SuperSU zip from recovery**

  In a futile attempt I tried to use the android recovery to push a SuperSU zip with its update from zip option. I knew this wouldn't work but I found something interesting. On the `Apply update from SD card` option I get an error saying `couldn't mount /sdcard`
- **Booting recovery images with fastboot**

  I have tried the `fastboot boot recovery.img` command to try to boot directly into the images. I get this

  ```
  downloading 'boot.img'...
  OKAY [  0.211s]
  booting...
  OKAY [  0.047s]
  finished. total time: 0.261s
  ```

  output but the device just restarts and boots normally into the normal OS.

### What I would like from this question <sub>(In order of importance)</sub>:

1. A way to root the device
2. A way to access a custom recovery (even if temporary)
3. Ability to install custom ROMs
4. A permanent custom recovery

Comment: First thing to look for is whether there's a custom recovery (e.g. TWRP) available for your device. You'll need that anyway. If there is, get it (installed). Then take a look at Magisk. Take a look at my article [Root for all: Magisk](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/magisk-1) to get an overview.

Comment: @Izzy I thought so, I can't find a custom recovery anywhere for my device. One of the recoverys I tried was the generic arm twrp and you can see the results of that in my post. Getting a recovery is the main problem I'm having; I'm fairly confident rooting after that.

Comment: Have you tried [TwrpBuilder](https://github.com/TwrpBuilder/TwrpBuilder)? Claims to generate a TWRP image from your stock recovery. I haven't tried it so far (I always check those things *before* I buy a device, to make sure TWRP and custom ROMs are available or the latter at least already "in the make"). That way I can root the device before unboxing :) (very first thing: unlock bootloader (no data to lose yet), flash TWRP, and only after that switch on for usage).